# How to create Rollback in TeamServices build definition?

Tags: team-foundation-server, release-management

I need to create rollback if deployment has failed.

[image: Build definition with task group (rollback db and ear file to WebSphere)]

I only need this task group to run when the previous deployment has failed.

I tried to run task without task group but just only one task is bypassed when the deployment works fine, I need when deploy is work bypassed the two task to rollback

[image: task group]

Comment: I fix this with "eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed')" in custom conditions thanks!